# OpenMp in Visual studio

Tags: c++, openmp

I am looking into OpenMp to speed up my application. In visual studio 2015 community, the following code works:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7
#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WIN7
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
    for (int i = 0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        std::stringstream s;
        s <<  "i: " << i << " thread: "<< omp_get_thread_num() << '\n';
        std::cout << s.str();
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

this prints:

```
i: 0 thread: 0
i: 13 thread: 1
i: 76 thread: 6
i: 64 thread: 5
i: 52 thread: 4
i: 26 thread: 2
i: 39 thread: 3
i: 88 thread: 7
```

When i try to use this same code in the same project, but a different class, like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
    for (auto i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        cout << " thread: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;


        for (auto j = 0; j < dim; j++)
        {
            dataset_fi[i * dim + j] = features_[fi][i][j];
        }
    }
```

it prints:

```
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
```

instead. What am i doing wrong here? Why would openmp work in one class but not another?

i have language/openmp enabled, and have added `/openmp` to the command line.

Thank you.

Comment: Without a full reproducer, it's hard to guess all necessary details.  OpenMP 2.0 standard (which is the most you can expect with msvc++) states explicitly: The for loop iteration variable must have a signed integer type

Comment: As msvc doesn't have full support for anything newer than C89 it may be hard to predict what happens with syntax which has varying meaning under newer standards.

Comment: Thank you! i have changed the for loop to an `int`, and yet see the same `thread 0` print.

Comment: A guess (since we don't have an executable example): your second case is nested somewhere inside an existing parallel region. You have not set OMP_NESTED=true, therefor no additional parallelism is happening. (But, that may be a good thing! You do not want exponential over-subscription...). Note that there are OpenMP compilers for Windows which implement modern OpenMP (e.g. Intel, Clang, ...)

Comment: Is the second code in another source file or the same source file (projects can include many source files)?

Comment: Hi! thank you all for your replies. The source code I am trying to add to is third party, and you can see it here:   https://github.com/IntelVCL/FastGlobalRegistration/blob/master/source/FastGlobalRegistration/app.cpp#L94

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve